# Transformar matriz em vetor

Tags: c#, array, .net, matriz, revisão-de-código

Estou fazendo alguns exercícios com matriz e array, e cheguei a seguinte situação:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int linha = 3;
        int coluna = 3;

        int[,] matriz = new int[linha, coluna];

        int count = 0;
        for (int l = 0; l < linha; l++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < coluna; c++)
            {
                matriz[l, c] = count;
                count++;
            }
        }

        var vetor = new int[matriz.Length];

        count = 0;
        for (int l = 0; l < linha; l++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < coluna; c++)
            {

                vetor[count] = matriz[l, c];
                count++;
            }
        }

        ReadKey();
    }
```

Gero essa matriz 3 x 3 e depois transformo em um array com base no tamanho da matriz.

- Tem como melhorar esse algoritmo ? Talvez usando LINQ ou outros recursos da linguagem para copiar os itens da matriz para o array.

Comment: O problema não é nem o algoritmo, é a desnecessidade dele. Sendo um algoritmo artificial a melhorai faria praticamente ele não existir. Se tem alguma regra que determine o artificialismo qual seria ela? Não sabemos o que pode ser feito para melhorar e o que não pode justamente por ser artificial. E no que está olhando. Por exemplo, organizar mais o código é um item a ser observado?  Padronizar o código é uma melhoria? Fazer o código ter menos linhas? E pode ficar menos legível? Se não pode, o que passaria ser ilegível? Por exemplo, pra mim, pela minha experiência,a resposta dada fez ficar pior

Comment: @Maniero boa, minha intenção era ver outras formas de fazer isso, só que sem precisar usar for dentro de for, talvez usando linq ou outros recursos do csharp para copiar os items para o array, irei alterar a pergunta para ficar mais claro.

Comment: Por `Estou fazendo alguns exercícios com matriz e array` entendo que seja um caso de exercitar a lógica e em geral pede-se para remover os `loops`.

Answer (score 2):

> Por "Estou fazendo alguns exercícios com matriz e array" entendo que seja um caso de exercitar a lógica e em geral pede-se para remover os loops.

Isso poderia ser feito em um único `for`:

```cs
for (var i = 0; i < linha * coluna; i++)
{
    vetor[i] = matriz[i/coluna, i % coluna];
}
```

Exemplo completo (com ligeiras modificações para facilitar a leitura):

```cs
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int linha = 3;
        int coluna = 4;

        var matriz = new string[linha, coluna];

        for (int l = 0; l < linha; l++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < coluna; c++)
            {
                matriz[l, c] = l.ToString() +"-"+ c.ToString();
            }
        }

        var vetor = new string[linha*coluna];

        for (var i = 0; i < linha * coluna; i++)
        {
            vetor[i] = matriz[i/coluna, i % coluna];
        }

        foreach (var elem in vetor)
            Console.WriteLine(elem);
    }
}
```

Link para fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lzz0Gc

Answer (score 1):

Eu não ia responder, mas quem me conhece sabe que tem caso não dá para deixar de fazer. Vide comentário porque eu acho este tipo de pergunta complicada, mas já tem uma resposta.

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var linhas = 3;
        var colunas = 3;
        var matriz = new int[linhas, colunas];
        for (int i = 0, count = 0; i < linhas; i++) for (var j = 0; j < colunas; j++) matriz[i, j] = count++;
        var vetor = new int[matriz.Length];
        for (int i = 0, count = 0; i < linhas; i++) for (var j = 0; j < colunas; j++) vetor[count++] = matriz[i, j];
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/wYS2Uv). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nLMzkh). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/FlatMatrix.cs).

Não tem nenhuma grande melhoria que pode ser feita, ainda que melhoria precisaria ser melhor definida. Como eu disse no comentário precisaria de parâmetro para saber o que pode ou não fazer, o que seria considerado melhoria e o que não seria. Sempre é possível fazer de uma forma muito diferente, daí a chamar de melhor vai uma distância.

Eu refiz escrevendo um código mais enxuto, limpo, curto, que eu gosto mais. Nem todo mundo gosta de código mais curto. As melhorias são mesmo cosméticas.

Eu padronizei o código (cada hora ele optava por fazer de uma forma diferente). Tirei o que não era necessário e diminui o escopo de algumas variáveis.

Dei nome melhor para as variáveis: se algo é um total deveria ser plural e neste tipo de manipulação o comum é usar variáveis `i` e `j`, o que inclusive elimina o `l` que é um péssimo nome porque sempre para o mesmo `1`.

O que eu não fiz é incluir coisas novas no algoritmo que não pedia e não tentei reduzir para um laço porque isso só piora a execução.

Além de passar ter uma multiplicação e duas divisões que não existam no original, e essas são as operações individuais mais custosas que um processador pode executar, ainda não reduziu a quantidade de *branches* que é o que poderia melhorar alguma coisa em termos de performance.

Usar o LINQ poderia fazer parecer um algoritmo melhor mas é uma ilusão. seria mais lento e em algum caso poderia até ser pior (acho que não acontece neste caso, mas existe uma situação que a enumeração aconteceria de forma exponencial). Na pergunta não fala nada sobre LINQ, só no comentário sugere que isto seria a possível melhora, que eu questiono que seja melhor, seria mais visivelmente simples, mas não necessariamente melhor. Por isso que que queria uma melhor definição do problema.

Se quiser insistir no LINQ pode fazer a transformação assim:

```
var vetor = matriz.OfType<int>().ToArray();
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/r5O6de). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GkLxHy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/FlatMatrix.cs).

Está trocando uma linha longa e outra declarando o *array* por uma curta, mas a performance será menor, mesmo que pouco.

Se eu fosse melhorar mais eliminaria quase todo o código que só existe nesta forma artificialmente. Eu ainda não vejo a necessidade de fazer a transformação, pode ter, mas precisaria ser justificado.